# Use bash to receive serial input then do some math with said input then send to virtual serial port for another app to read

Tags: bash, arduino

I have an arduino sending me some numbers through serial @9600 baud. Two values seperated by a comma sent every 500ms or so. `cat /dev/ttyACM0` looks like this: 10.5,20.3 with the numbers ranging from -10 to 100. I have an application which receives this information and puts it on a graph for me to visualize. My problem is the application in question lacks the ability to do any sort of math with the values given so I am stuck with what the arduino can send for graphing.

I need to take the numbers and "condition" them so to speak. Better put in pseudocode below:

```
read value1 //values parsed from serial using comma as a seperator
read value2 //I have no idea how to do that but I know its doable lol

var kwh = 0;
var lastReadTime = systemTimeMillis();

Loop {
var addKwh = (value1 + value2) * 120 * (systemTimeMillis() - lastReadTime)/1000/60/60/1000
kwh = kwh + addKwh
lastReadTime = systemTimeMillis();
echo $value1 + "," + $value2 + "," + $kwh > virtualSerialPortForOtherApplicationToRead
}
```

Now - I know what you are thinking - why not do the "conditioning" on the arduino? Well I need to be able to reset this value at the end of the day hence the need for system time which is a pain in the butt to pass back to arduino and have it be reliable.

So my thought is to make a bash script that reads the incoming data from the arduino serial stream and "conditions" it as needed and then send the conditioned data to my other application via a dummy serial port. I am pretty much clueless on how to do the virtual serial port part of this whole thing. And my knowledge of bash is also limited so I really appreciate examples. I guess I also have no idea if any of this is possible but I am hoping to find a solution.

Another reason for bash is I will be able to easily also send the conditioned values to a csv for my own use as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a tutorial forum ... please ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: start with using bash to write a value to a serial port ... a python script may be simpler to implement

Comment: Yes, python would be a great choice for this.   python is pretty much the de-facto standard language for programming arduino boards, and there's the [Arduino-Python3 Command API](https://pypi.org/project/arduino-python3/) library module for communicating with and controlling arduinos connected to your computer.    python also comes with a [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library for reading and writing CSV files.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project, but it seems, unfortunately, too broad as a question. I think that you need to divide this project up into chunks, and have a go at solving each chunk, and then when you hit a specific issue, *then* ask a question about it here. But yes, use Python, and not Bash, for communication with the Arduino, - whereas C++ is the de-facto language for actually *programming* the board

Comment: That said, this question (and the linked to questions in the right hand column) on SO *might* help: [Bash, serial I/O and Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3918032/4424636)

Comment: @cas most arduino boards are programmed in C++

Comment: Yes, C++ is the **actual** standard language.  I should have said "de-facto standard **scripting** language" because that's what python is for Arduino - it's probably the most common language aside from C++ used to program Arduinos, e.g. with python-to-c++ compilers like [pyxie](https://pypi.org/project/pyxie/).  Or, at least, it was the last time I looked into Arduinos, which was several years ago.